# How to get previous week using YEARWEEK in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I can query my items from this week using:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE YEARWEEK(receivedOn, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

But I would like to fetch items from previous  week, or previous previous week. How can I do it?

Something like this (for previous week):

```
YEARWEEK(receivedOn - 1 * week, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE() - 1 * week, 1)
```

for previous previous  week

```
YEARWEEK(receivedOn - 2 * week, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE() - 2 * week, 1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original query, and all answers that were given, applies a date function on the stored column. As Gordon Linoff points out, this is inefficient because it *cannot* take advantage of an index on the column.

I am going to suggest using direct filtering instead. You can get the beginning of the current week (starting Monday, as in your original code) with the following expression:

```
current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
```

From there on, here is how to filter on dates that belong to the current week:

```
select * 
from data 
where receivedon >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
  and receivedon <  current_date + interval 7 - weekday(current_date) day
```

If you want to filter on the previous week:

```
where receivedon >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) + 7 day
  and receivedon <  current_date + interval weekday(current_date) day
```

And on the the week before that:

```
where receivedon >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) + 14 day
  and receivedon <  current_date + interval weekday(current_date) + 7  day
```

Answer (score 0):

Current week of year `yearweek(sysdate() )`

Previous week of year `yearweek(sysdate() -interval 1 week )`

Previous previous week of year `yearweek(sysdate() -interval 2 week )`

.. and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
WHERE YEARWEEK(receivedOn, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, 1)
```

Note:  This expression cannot make use of an index so it might not be the most efficient way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  You don't want to adjust receivedOn, and need to use the proper date arithmetic syntax:

```
YEARWEEK(receivedOn, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1)
```